# One to two (1:2) relation between two tables

Tags: database, database-design

I'm working on some asp.net application, I got stuck in following business.

Suppose we have a person, and he can open both types of accounts and each account has some transaction history. Person table has some primary key say PPK, and customer table has some PK as PIN.

My question is how to solve/present this scenario in database, relation of  person table to customer table is 1:2 as no person can have more than two account. and what about that transaction table? that holds all transaction history for some specific account? shall I make two transaction table (which is really a bad idea because as account type exceeds transaction tables exceeds).

Can I build their relation as 1:* (then I may need another table for that. it holds Fk of both table. )

or Can make pin as unique key and always open database for like checking limit of accounts (i.e. two).

I really need some suggestions.

All suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

P.S: If you dont understand the question please ask me before reporting it away please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either do something like this:

[image]

Or something like this:

[image]

The first model allows adding more accounts by just changing the CHECK (in case requirements change in the future), while the second would require adding another column in such case.

*NOTE: The above assumes both account types are structurally identical, so they "fit" into same table. If that's not the case, you can use inheritance.*

Comment: I'm very very sorry, but I didn't understand this, a little more explanation would be very helpful.
Thanks @branko

Comment: @SikanderHayyat Could you please be more specific as to what exactly you couldn't understand? Is the notation used in the diagrams unclear to you, or is it something else?

Comment: Actually its the notations that confused me

Comment: @SikanderHayyat OK, this is a notation MS Visio uses for ER diagrams. There is no "standard" ER notation, but this one is probably one of the simplest. Each box is one table, with table name at the top. Below are field names, bold denotes NOT NULL. PK is primary key and U is unique constraint. Arrow represents foreign key (from referencing to referenced table), FK denotes foreign key attributes (in referencing table).

Comment: @SikanderHayyat So for example, in the top diagram, the ACCOUNT table has primary key {ACCOUNT_ID}, composite unique constraint {PERSON_ID, ACCOUNT_TYPE} and foreign key {PERSON_ID} "pointing" to PERSON table.

Comment: Thanks @branko. I appreciate your help. With this diagram explanition, I can now understand the answer. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you have a person table and an account table with a foreign key relationship between the two which is 1 person to many accounts. Then you have a transaction table that is related to the account id in the account table which is also 1 account to many transacations.

Now to enforce the limit of only two accounts being allowed, for that you want a trigger that checks when a record is being inserted or updated to amek sure the person currently has no more than one other record.

Comment: I'd to open database for at least two time, first check limit then feed data, and how can I represent this in erd? I mean relation? 1 to many or one to two (that sounds a little odd).
Thanks @HLGEM